# How to save dataframe from outside the project

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, interrupted-exception

I have a pandas dataframe in my jupyter notebook project, but my project stopped responding. Is there any way to save the dataframe from outside my code, like using anaconda prompt or something like that?
Thanks in advance.